# ввод параметров для тестирования с клавиатуры (JUnit)

Tags: java, тестирование, junit

Начал осваивать JUnit. Возник такой вопрос. Можно ли в тесте задавать параметры (actual, expected) с клавиатуры? Если да, то как это правильно сделать? 
Делал следующим образом, но консоль просто виснет и выкидывает исключение:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Testing {
    private String input;
    private String expectedResult;
    private Challenges challenges;

    @Before
    public void initialize(){
        challenges = new Challenges();
    }

    public Testing(String input, String expectedResult){
        this.input = input;
        this.expectedResult = expectedResult;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection inputStrings(){
        return getCustomParams();
    }

    public static List<String[]> getCustomParams(){
        List<String[]> params = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            params.add(new String[] {scanner.nextLine(), scanner.nextLine()});
        }
        return params;
    }

    @Test
    public void testChallenge(){
        System.out.println("Input is: " + input);
        System.out.println("Expected Result is: " + expectedResult);
        assertEquals(expectedResult, challenges.camelCase(input));
    }
}
```

Поясните пожалуйста, можно ли вообще реализовать такую задачу и как это сделать правильно? Хочу, чтобы тест ожидал, пока я введу определенное количество параметров и ожидаемых результатов и тогда выводил результаты тестирования. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это неправильное использование JUnit. Возможно это можно как-нибудь сделать, но лучше не стоит.

Суть автоматизированного тестирования в том, чтобы подготовить набор тестов/параметров заранее, чтобы тесты в дальнейшем можно было прогонять без ручного ввода.

Задача в том, чтобы подобрать набор параметров, который покрывает все случаи.

Внесите все необходимые параметры в самом коде:

```
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection inputStrings(){
    return Arrays.asList(
        new String[][] {     
            { "hello_world", "helloWorld" }, 
            { "no one but me", "noOneButMe" }, 
            ...
    }
);
```

Можете попробовать вынести параметры в отдельный файл, но суть от этого не изменится.

Поддержка консольного ввода в тестах проблематична, т.к. каждый тест запускается в отдельном потоке (тесты должны быть независимы). Если нужно написать консольное приложение, то это можно сделать и без JUnit.